# Django. Сheck activation code

Tags: django

UPDATE!

The activation code is stored in the database, but I can not call it as a function of **activation**
**Gives an error message:**

> TypeError at /account/activation/18d2ecbee1fd15440bbcfdf942c071a2f5b8d0ff/
>   activation() got an unexpected keyword argument 'activation_key'

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class EmailForm(forms.Form):

    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control input-lg',
               'placeholder': 'Ваш E-mail'}))
```

views.py

```
import datetime
import hashlib
import random

from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, logout, login
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import render

from forms import *
from models import *


def register(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EmailForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form_email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            salt = hashlib.sha1(str(random.random())).hexdigest()[:5]
            activation_key = hashlib.sha1(salt+form_email).hexdigest()
            key_expires = datetime.datetime.today() + datetime.timedelta(2)

            subject = 'Activation your e-mail'
            from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
            to_email = [form_email]
            message_email = "Hi, i'm link activate e-mail! \
            http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/activation/%s" % activation_key
            send_mail(subject,
                      message_email,
                      from_email,
                      to_email,
                      fail_silently=True)
            code = ActivationEmail.objects.create(activation_key=activation_key)
            code.save()

            return render(request, 'registration/activate.html', locals())

    else:
        form = EmailForm()

    return render(request, 'registration/register.html', locals())


def activation(request, code):
    try:
        active = ActivationEmail.objects.get(activation_key=code)
    except ActivationEmail.DoesNotExist:
        active = None
        active.validated = True
    if not active:
        raise Http404
    print "USER WAS HERE?!"
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/account/wizard/')
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^register/', views.register, name='registration'),
                       url(r'^activation/(?P<activation_key>\w+)/', views.activation, name='activation'),
                       url(r'^login/$', views.user_login, name='login'),
                       url(r'^logout/$', views.user_logout, name='logout'),
```

Just can not figure out how to do next; (

Comment: Can you show me User model? 
What exactly are you not able to figure out? Do you have a boolean column say `is_activated` to mark a user active? Also, you need to store the `activation_key` in your DB.

Comment: At the moment I do not have a model. And I suppose it should look something like this: `activation_key = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
    validated = models.BooleanField(default=False)`

Answer (score 1):

You will need to

1- You will need to create a new table to store the activation keys, such that you can create a new entry before sending the email

2.- On the user clicking the activation link, that link should be sufficient for you to find the record you created before sending the email

3.- If everything matches, then set a user.is_active type thing on your user model.

But all that said, you are reinventing the wheel here. There are several top notch packages you can use with this and more. I would recommend `django-allauth` with also give you social login support (e.g. facebook). If you just want the activation portion, there is an older package called `django-registration`. There are a few others if you search around, but the point is you don't need to implement this (and you probably don't want to mess around with registration if you are not an expert)

Comment: Thanks for the answer)
I do not reinvent the wheel, I try to bend it)))
1. I need to create a model for the activation key? Or, you can not create a model to add to the database?
2. After activating the user is redirected to a different form, and already there I will use the active user

Could you write a couple of lines for example?
Thanking you in advance!

Comment: Can you explain what you need to bend? Everything you have described so far can be achieved with django-allauth

Comment: How to save the model generated activation key and refer to it when activated?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I understand what you want to do with the activation code. I am assuming what you are trying to achieve is ensuring that you do not allow users to login before confirming their email, making sure the registration has a real email. django-allauth does it all. You don't have to worry about any of this. It will use its own data models to create an EmailAddressed and EmailConfirmation tables that will use to do this all. You can, if you want, intercept this using signals (see their docs). They also support having users enter multiple emails, which each has to be verified

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your real issue. Good luck